# Making skewed elements on image transparent

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've tried following a guide on Youtube for help with this, and I can get it to work - sort of.

I'm trying to place two divs inside a section, where the top one is to house an image, and the bottom one be place for text etc.

The thing I'd like, is for the the top one to have a skewed razorblade dip in the middle, so the image sort of bleeds onto the bottom div.

I've managed to make the skew elements and place them where I'd like, but I when I turn them transparent, they seem to disappear.

Example: https://imgur.com/DsqNvZI

My CSS:

```
.section_1 {
    height: 800px;
    width: auto;
    background: red;
}

.section_image {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(lolsovs.jpg);
}

.section_image::after, .section_image::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: -1em;
}

.section_image::after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: skew(0, -20deg);
    z-index: 100;
}

.section_image::before {
    right: 50%;
    transform: skew(0, 20deg);
}

.section_text {
    background: purple;
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

I'm still a novice when it comes to all of this stuff, so go gentle on me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I when I turn them transparent, they seem to disappear.

Which is logical since you made them transparent. I advise you to consider another way to achieve this. You may simply consider some linear-gradient to color the bottom part to have this transparent part on the top:

```css
.image {
  height: 200px;
  background:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/) center/cover no-repeat;
}

.bottom {
  height:200px;
  margin-top:-50px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,purple 51%)calc(50% - 21px) 0/40px 50px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,purple 51%)calc(50% + 20px) 0/40px 50px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(purple,purple)100% 0/calc(50% - 40px) 50px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(purple,purple)0 0/calc(50% - 40px) 50px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(purple,purple)0 50px/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="bottom">

</div>
```

And for better handling you can use CSS variable to adjust dimension:

```css
.image {
  height: 200px;
  background:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/) center/cover no-repeat;
}

.bottom {
  height:200px;
  margin-top:calc(-1 * var(--h,50px));
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,purple 51%)calc(50% - (var(--w,50px) /2)) 0/var(--w,50px) var(--h,50px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,purple 51%)calc(50% + (var(--w,50px) /2)) 0/var(--w,50px) var(--h,50px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(purple,purple)100% 0/calc(50% - var(--w,50px)) var(--h,50px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(purple,purple)0 0/calc(50% - var(--w,50px)) var(--h,50px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(purple,purple)0 var(--h,50px)/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="bottom" style="--h:80px;--w:100px">

</div>
```

Comment: What an absolute thing of beauty you are my kind friend! Thanks alot!

Comment: @aroabarberan please pay attention while editing posts ! you completely screwed the content